# How to set session for another asp.net application from current application in SSO

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am developing single sign on application using formauthentication.  I didnt have any issue until my application uses membership and sql server state maintenance. But one of my other application using session for checking the user is logged in or not.

In this case i cant able to login to the application which is using session. I am trying to set session from the SSO application, but it is showing the session is always null.

Can anybody help me please?

Here is my sso application code where i am setting the session.

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(sUserName, sPass))
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
      1,                                     // ticket version
      sUserName,                              // authenticated username
      DateTime.Now,                          // issueDate
      DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),           // expiryDate
      isPersistent,                          // true to persist across browser sessions
      "Test SSO",                              // can be used to store additional user data
      FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);  // the path for the cookie

    // Encrypt the ticket using the machine key
    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    // Add the cookie to the request to save it
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(sUserName, false);
}
Session["UserName"] = sUserName;
```

This is the code of another application which is using session.

```
if (Session["UserName"] != null)
{
    HostPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostPath"].ToString();
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login.aspx");
}
```

Here i am getting the session name is null always, so it is redirecting me the login page always.

I need to set the session of my second application from my SSO application. This is my requirement help please.

Thanks

Comment: Take the authcookie of one application and decrypt it in another ?